# Example to show that multiplication by ideals and intersection of submodules do not commute

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

The key point of [question about typical proof of Krull Intersection Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761197/question-about-typical-proof-of-krull-intersection-theorem) is that multiplication by ideals and intersection of submodules do not commute. Can anyone give me an example of this?

That is,

> I'm looking for $A$-modules $M, N, P$ and an ideal $\mathfrak a \subset A$ such that  $M \subset P$, $N \subset P$  and $\mathfrak a (M \cap N) \neq \mathfrak a M \cap \mathfrak a N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit contrived, but take $A = \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ and let $I = (x^2, xy-xz)$. Set $P = A / I$. Then take $M = (x+ I,y+ I)$ and $N = (x+ I,z+I)$, $\mathfrak{a} = (x)$. We have $\mathfrak{a}M = (xy+I)$ and $\mathfrak{a}N = (xz+I)$, so
$$\mathfrak a M \cap \mathfrak a N = (xy+I) = (xz+I)$$ 
because we have identified $xy - xz \in I$. On the other hand, $M \cap N = (x+ I)$, so
$$ \mathfrak a (M \cap N) = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Consider $\,(x,y)((x)\cap(y)) = (x,y)(xy)$ in $\,\Bbb  Z[x,y]$

But distributed it is $\ (x^2,xy)\cap (xy,y^2) = (xy) $ since

$\quad ax^2\!+bxy = cxy + dy^2\ \overset{\large y=0,}{\underset{\large x=1}\Rightarrow}\,a=0;\ \overset{\large x=0}{\underset{\large y=1}\Rightarrow}\,d=0 $